# Keystore and key alias errors when build apk release

Tags: android, apk, release, android-keystore

I have created release *.apk files by build with keystore (*.jks) and alias successful. I deleted jks file and tried to created a new one to build again. However, I could not rebuild project due to "**The system cannot find the file specified**". It's look like Android Studio still remember the old *.jks file.

My question is: Is it possible to create a new jks file and rebuild project or only use the first one?

Answer (score 0):

If you lost your .jks file then you have to request Google to allow you to use new jks file. Simply fill the form for this.